# Redis, redis fatal error can't open config file

Tags: database, windows, configuration, redis, nosql

I am running Redis on Windows and have not been able to run it using the config file.

I tried running:

```
redis-server 'filepath'/conf/redis.conf
```

but I get the error saying

```
"redis fatal error can't open config file"
```

How can I resolve this issue and have the Redis server read the config file?

Answer (score 3):

For windows:

> redis-server "CONFIG_FILE_PATH"

Please make sure that config and log file have file read and write permission.
You can also specify the config path for Linux in the same way.

Comment: Can you elaborate where to get the config file path?

Comment: You can find the config files in "conf" folder under Redis installation folder.

For example, C:\Program Files\Redis\conf\

Answer (score 2):

> "Fatal error, can't open config file"

Redis server might have no read privilege on this config file or config file doesn't exist.

Comment: How do I grant it privilege to read the file, if that's the case?

Comment: I'm not familiar with windows. This error is caused by the line `if ((fp = fopen(filename,"r")) == NULL)`, which means redis server can't open that file in read mode. Maybe you could google [windows set file privilege](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=windows+set+file+privilege) .

Comment: Did it with sudo and file exist, same issue

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how I solved mine

```
redis-server C:/Users/<name>/Downloads/redis/64bit/redis.conf & --daemonize yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try any command, Just double click on Redis app.

Comment: This works on my mac system also. Try clicking redis-server on redis folder to start the server and the use redis-cli to enter the command panel. Finally "Ping" :)

Comment: Is this a windows specific question and answer?

Comment: yes windows specific answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is saved in UTF-8, if the .conf file is created from copying and pasting from the browser different unsupported encodings can be passed down to the image.